# Typeset aligned blocks in two columns

Tags: vertical-alignment

I want to produce something like this:

[image]

So, basically, it is a table without drawn borders. Unfortunately, even `longtable` and `longtabu` don't allow me to break one cell over several pages.

I have also tried using package `tasks`, but I cannot get rid of the labels, and it is still not allowed to break the items over pages.

In general, I am asking how to control alignment over pages, because I don't know any ways to do that, except using `longtabu` and `minipage`.

Here is **MWE** with `tasks` and `longtabu`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}


\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

%   \settasks{counter-format= (tsk[a]), label-offset=0.75em, after-skip=\smallskipamount}
\settasks{counter-format={}, label-offset=0em, after-skip=0pt}
\noindent%
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task \lipsum[2]
        \task \lipsum[1]
        \task Another sentence
        \task \lipsum[2]
    \end{tasks}

\noindent%
\begin{longtabu}{p{5cm} p{5cm}}

    \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2-4]\\
    \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2-4]

\end{longtabu}
```

Comment: The `paracol` package might help, I think. It can break across pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggest in my comment, maybe the `paracol` package is what you're after:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\lipsum[1]

\switchcolumn

\lipsum[2]
\switchcolumn*[\vspace{1cm}]
\lipsum[1-2]

\switchcolumn

\lipsum[3-5]

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution, thank you. As I understand, `ragged2e` is not required?

Comment: I didn't use it really. You can see it should have been used in the  image, but I think it is only because of the `lipsum` text, which latex doesn't know where to hyphenate.

Comment: it's better at hyphenating lipsum if you use `\usepackage[latin]{babel}`

Comment: @David Carlisle: I didn't know that. I must say it only has the word endings from Latin, and I always found it quite strange…

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I prefer polyglossia. I just don't need it in MWE.